# Is there a way to access Borland Star Team via python?

Tags: python, starteam

is there a way to access Borland Star Team via python? e.g. log in , check out, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I can see, unfortunately there is no native StarTeam API for python.

But according to this: [The StarTeam APIs](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2009/en/sdk_documentation/guide/overview.html), I think you can call their java API functions from python by those ways: [Calling Java from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python)

Also if you are on Windows, you can just use their Windows COM interfaces.