# calling java classes from python

Tags: java, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling Java from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python)

I am not much familiar with java.. 
 but i want to use a java library (3rd party) inside python.?
Lets say I have three libraries.

```
foo.java,bar.java,foobar.java
```

And then.. they define classes and their contructor takes one variable each

```
int foo1, int bar1 respectively

Now.. foo.java  and bar.java imports foobar.java
```

So basically.. i want to interact with foo.java and bar.java.. and then they interact with other java files..

How do i solve this.. 
I looked into other stackoverflow questions as well but most of them are like very high level questions for me whereas i feel i have a very simple need.
any pointers
thanks

Comment: It's not going to be easy, unless you use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/). If not then you probably have to make interface modules in C using JNI, or to find other similar libraries that exist already for Python or C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

1) [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) or 
2) [JPYPE](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/)