# Using a jar internally in Python | OSX Issues

Tags: java, python, macos, jar

I'm reading pdf files with python. And in my script, i'm calling a jar file by command line using os.system.

Two things here:

- OSX annoyingly keeps redirecting me to desktop everytime the jar is called. I can optmize that, but I don't want OSX to do that; and
- Isn't there a way to no actually open java internally ? Like attaching the code inside my python script. Let's just say I don't want the user to see java being opened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this mean: "OSX annoyingly keeps redirecting me to desktop everytime the jar is called"?

Comment: What part of it? It means what it means. My desktop end up being the desktop the jar is being executed in. That is, if i'm in presentation mode in some IDE, for example, running the script, the desktop i'm in goes out of focus. Cause a new app has been opened in another desktop(java).

Comment: I don't understand your use of "desktop" here. Mac OS X has only one Desktop.

Comment: Well, there's a big button here in the mission control telling me I can create another desktop. But that's not the point. When you open java thru a python script, that runs on some IDE. Mac OS X tries to show you what's currently being opened by redirecting you to somewhere where you can see the dock. Thus, you can see the app popping up. Right?

Comment: Also, that's kinda not my main problem. What's really annoying me right now is that I just wanted a way to "attach" a jar file in my script. Making the user not know it's running at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may want take a look at [similar discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python). To summarize the discussion, you can use [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html).

There is also another project called [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/), however that seems to be a very old implementation (way back in 2009) and no updates thence.