# execute method in cmd without main function

Tags: java, cmd, program-entry-point

I need to execute a method in `.java` or `.class` but this class doesn't have a `main` function (I can't use `main` function  because it has no return value) I must execute this method in cmd , Is there any way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: What kind of problem you are trying to solve? For what do you need to call direct class method? I think, that you may call your method from `main()` and print result to `cmd` with `System.out.println()`.

Comment: other program (edit with Python) will execute this method and  in this method I`ll do something  then  I should return a value tell the caller if this method goes wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call Java class from Python and get result from it, then you should use something like `JPype` or `Pyjnius`.

See [Calling Java from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python)

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Java has methods, not functions.

Up until Java 7, it was possible to run Java without a main method using the static block, but this was removed as of Java 7, because the static block was not supposed to use this way.

If you want to run it: add a main method.

Comment: Oh,thanks, I will corrected my syntex (In mounts of Chinese`s option function is method  and method is function ) the most difficult is I need to run this class file and it must give me a return value  how can I do this ?

Comment: Function and method here are not english or chinese notions, they are programming terms (independent on languages). There are differences between them.
To where do you want a value to be returned? To the main method? You want the main method to return a value? This is not possible.
You can call any other method by another program, and the method it calls can return a value, though this may not be the main method, or any other method with return type void.