# What happens in the backstage when we import a jar to pyspark shell

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I understand that pyspark shell uses Python interpreter. How is it possible to import a jar to it? What happens in the backstage that makes it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "import a jar"?

Comment: dupe @user8371915 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684842/calling-java-scala-function-from-a-task/34412182#34412182

Comment: @eliasah Maybe, but I wouldn't cast a vote without clarification. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443114/what-happens-in-the-backstage-when-we-import-a-jar-to-pyspark-shell?noredirect=1#comment89858719_51443712) suggests that OP is not really interested in PySpark.

Comment: But the OP accepted the answer...

Comment: @eliasah Maybe dupe of [Calling Java from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652554/8371915)?

Comment: Definitely but I’ve already cast a vote as not clear...

Comment: @user8371915 Am interested in understanding how things work and was confused about having jars imported to Python. I'm currently building an application that should read data from Kudu and load it to Hive using PySpark. Currently the only way I can use the kudu-spark lib is through PySpark/Spark-Submit

Comment: In that case please follow the link shared by eliasah. It explains how to interface Python and Java in Spark and links to more detailed explanations

Comment: @user8371915 yep, am doing that. Should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short nothing, because you simply *import a jar* to Python interpreter (well, unless you use Jython, but that's a different story).

In PySpark Python interpreter communicates with JVM using sockets.

- Python serializes data (some form of it) or command and sends it over socket to JVM process.
- JVM process deserializes the thing, decides what to do with it, computes the result and sends it over socket to Python interpreter.

If any import from jar happens, it happens on JVM in it's "natural" environment.

Specific tool that it is used is [Py4j](https://www.py4j.org/), so you can check it with you're interested in implementation details, but other similar tools exist out there.

Comment: Thank you! So if I want to use the original Python interpreter (not PySpark) and import a jar that contain classes and methods to it, I'll need to implement this myself using Py4J?