# Use python to connect to Java GUI read and control the Interface

Tags: python, automation, py4j

Hi I'm fairly new to this but I thought I would try and ask if there is a way for python3.7 to read information from a java based UI. I want to control center buttons, read values and configure settings. I was hoping it would do this via some sort of automation library like py4j or selenium. But my app is not web based.

I'm using windows 10.

Comment: This is not an easy problem. There's a number of ways to go about this.. maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3793523/3280538

Comment: This is kind of the the right track I do like this idea the most so far. I guess I would need to see some code of py4j being used to control a java gui to know for sure if it will work. It would be great if it still allowed me to use my mouse and keyboard during the automation of gui.