# How to decrypt custom encrypted message in Python Confluent_Kafka using key.deserializer and value.deserializer?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

My team is using confluent_kafka to produce real time streaming and is being pushed to a queue using custom encryption. The technology behind is Java.

I am trying to consume the messages using python from the topic and able to do so but unable to decrypt it using python.

```
from confluent_kafka import *
import os
from confluent_kafka.serialization import StringDeserializer

os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = "http://username:password@proxy.com:8080"


c = DeserializingConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka.abcd.com:1010',
    'group.id':'SharedKafka2',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'latest',
    'security.protocol':'SSL',
    'ssl.ca.location':'CARoot.pem',
    'ssl.certificate.location':'certificate.pem',
    'ssl.key.location':'key.pem',
    'value.deserializer': StringDeserializer()
})

c.subscribe(['SharedKafka2_Topic'])


print("ConsumerStarted")
while True:
    msg = c.poll()
    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        if msg.error().code() == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
            continue
        else:
            print(msg.error())
            break

    print(msg.value())
```

**Output** = `b'\x85s\n\x0e{!G\xc7\xdfaV\x8e\x03a\xc4\x8e\xe1\xbc\xf4\xf4F\xb5<{\xecD\xc2\xf8jNN`

I am unable to provide the custom encryption key in value deserialiser. Below is how it is done in java:

```
props.put("key.deserializer","com.aexp.sec.kafka.serializers.CryptoDeSerializer");
props.put("value.deserializer","com.aexp.sec.kafka.serializers.CryptoDeSerializer");
props.put("CRYPTO_KEY_DESERIALIZER", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put("CRYPTO_VALUE_DESERIALIZER", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
**props.put(String.format("%s_APIGEE_ENDPOINT", topic), apigeeUrl);
props.put("ENVIRONMENT", environment);
props.put(String.format("%s_KEY_IDENTIFIER", topic), keyIdentifier);
props.put(String.format("%s_APIGEE_CLIENT_ID", topic), clientID);
props.put(String.format("%s_APIGEE_CLIENT_SECRET", topic), clientSecret);**

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                buff.write(record.value()+"\n");
                buff.flush();
            }
        }
```

How to decrypt string format using custom decryption using python?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Confluent Python limitation. The Java program relies on this custom deserializer called `com.aexp.sec.kafka.serializers.CryptoDeSerializer` and thus there is no much anyone could help here. What you would need to do is come up with a equal implementation in Python that does the same logic implemented in the custom deserializer and then register it while creating your consumer:

```
c = DeserializingConsumer({
'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka.abcd.com:1010',
'group.id':'SharedKafka2',
'auto.offset.reset': 'latest',
'security.protocol':'SSL',
'ssl.ca.location':'CARoot.pem',
'ssl.certificate.location':'certificate.pem',
'ssl.key.location':'key.pem',
'value.deserializer': YourCustomDeserializerInPython()
```

})

If possible, try to reach out to whoever implemented the `CryptoDeSerializer` class in Java to understand how your code in Python needs to look like.

Comment: Sure Ricardo. I will try to implement that and will let you know. Thank for your response. :)

Comment: Seems like it is impossible to write decryption code in python. com.aexp.sec.kafka.serializers.CryptoDeSerializer is a jar used across organisation.  Is there a possibility we can use this Jar in python?

Comment: It is, as you can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python